# Android Lollipop with Nexus 5 - Proximity & Notification Bar

Tags: notifications, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, proximity-sensor

I've updated my non-rooted, Nexus 5 with an OTA update to Android 5.0 Lollipop and since then I have noticed quite a few things.
I am not sure if those are bugs or not.

- The Proximity Sensor does not turn off the screen when I am on the call. Network Calls or Viber or Google Hangouts, all the same.
- When any notification arrives, the notification is not clickable. I.E when any hangout call or WhatsApp message arrives, they cannot be clicked until the notification bar is dragged down.

Any guesses?

Comment: It's not new that you need to open the notification tray to click on notifications. As for the prox sensor, other Nexus 5 users with problems after updating have found that a (backup followed by a) factory reset can fix the problem. You might try thatl

Comment: @DanHulme No but the notification preview is supposed to be clickable (atleast it looks like it) & yes thanks, will try that.

Comment: The notifications are clickable. You need to double click the notification to open the app on lock screen.

Comment: @VishnuPrasadKallummel Things started working normal after restarting my phone. Its weird though. I have to restart it regularly. Or some features like: Brightness/Proximity stop working.

Comment: I would recommend a factory reset. If it is feasible.